# How to extrach HTML tags to identify completed tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a web site that generates this content.

[image]

Here is the HTML behind the page.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to scrape out the 3, 15, and 28.  There are 3 blank nodes in the same row too.  I want to capture everything because sometimes these numbers will be filled in.  Then, on the next row there is 25, and on the row below that there is 16.  Here's the generic code I have to get things started.

```
page_source = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    url = 'https://airflow.com/admin/?page={}'.format(i)
    page_source.append(url)

# count items in urllist
num = len(page_source)

# And grab the page HTML source
# The webdriver will wait for a page to load by default via .get() method.
for line in page_source:
    print(line)
    wd.get(line)
    html_page = wd.page_source
    soup = bs(html_page, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        #print(link.get('href'))
        string = link.get('href')
        id = re.match('(.*)_id=(\w+)', string).group(2)
        print(id)
```

Comment: If possible, could you copy the HTML snippet and paste it into your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bs4` to find and pair all `text` and `circle` tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(content, 'html.parser')
result = [{'text':a.text, 'color':b['stroke']} for a, b in zip(d.find_all('text'), d.find_all('circle')) if a.text]
```

Comment: @ryguy72 Glad to help!

Comment: One more quick question, if you don't mind.  I am running this:
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

It gives all href elements, right.  I want some, but not others.  I don't want these elements: javascript:void(0)
/admin/?showPaused=False

I do want these:
/admin/airflow/trigger?dag_id=barra_cxe1s_monthly_smgm_history
/admin/airflow/tree?dag_id=barra_cxe1s_monthly_smgm_history&num_runs=25
Only after the '_id=' characters and before the '&' character, or line break.

Comment: I tried this regex:
    string = link.get('href')
    id = re.match('(.*)_id=(\w+)', string).group(2)
    print(id)

I'm getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'.  I think a lot will fail, and that's OK because it doesn't match the regex pattern, but I don't want the code to stop when it encounters an error.

Comment: @ryguy72 To avoid the `AttributeError: 'NoneType'`, I suggest specifying part of the desired `href` value by providing an `re.compile` object in the dictionary passed to `find_all`: `soup.find_all('a', {'href':re.compile('_id\=')})`. The results from the latter will only contain `a` tags with the `href` including an HTML request `id` parameter. Of course, you can always update the regex expression in `re.compile`, but this will at least get you started.

Comment: Wow.  That's awesome.  I guess I've got a lot to learn.  Thank you!!